# Read a file and add elements in new array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Here my code. I want to declare dynamic array and next thing is to be able to read file and add elements in array. it is compiling, but I do not see result. Your suggestion is welcome.

```
int main(int argc, char** agrv)
{
    if(argc < 2 || argc > 2)
    {
        cerr << "You have to provide a file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    string myFile = agrv[1];

    ifstream file(myFile.c_str());

    if (!file)
    {
        cerr << "Error, file do not exist" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Student students;
    string number_student, name_student, surname_student, code_student;
    double number_student;


 // Declare an new array
     DynamicArray<Student>students; 

    while(file >>number_student >> name_student >> surname_student >> code_student)
    {
        students.add(student);
    }

        for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
        cout << students[i] << endl;
```

To provide solution to my project

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Show the code that you have written for your `DynamicArray` class template and explain the problem you have with that code.

Comment: ***it is compiling, but I do not see result.*** Use your debugger to figure out what exactly is happening. Don't just press the key in your IDE that starts the debugger. You need to instead use the debugger to step through your code 1 line at a time stopping after each line is executed and look at the variables and flow.

Comment: Please save yourself the headache of issues like this one, by using `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` is designed to handle run-time capacities.  It handles dynamic memory for you.

Comment: Is it crash or running infinitly? also you should pinpoint the line it crashes by useing a debugger or adding `cerr<<`line_number s  after every statement

Comment: What exactly do you think this line is doing? `while(file >>number_student >> name_student >> surname_student >> code_student)` I don't think your code even compiles because I don't think `student` is defined.

Comment: Save a few brain cells. `if(argc < 2 || argc > 2)` -> `if(argc != 2)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you used the same name `students` for 2 variables in the code.

> Student students

and

> DynamicArray<Students> students;

I think you probably wanted to name one of them `student` and the other `students` but made a typo mistake that lead to 2 `students`? When you're calling `students.add(student)`, it is obvious there is no variable named `student` to add to the array.

Then again, you have both `string number_student` and `double number_student` the same variable name. I have no idea why would you need 2 different variables for this one because your code didn't provide the background information about it, so at the moment I will eliminate the `double number_student` one for simplicity.

Second, there is some logic hole in your code. You used these strings `number_student`, `name_student`, `surname_student` and `code_student` to store the variable, but I don't see you use them again. My guess is that you're having a struct or class name `Student` and you want to store those variables into `Student`. Since you didn't provide your struct/class `Student`, I cannot help you fix it, but I can write you an example of it.

```
struct Student {
   string number_student;
   string name_student;
   string surname_student;
   string code_student;
}
```

To add a new student each time, you must call the `Student student` inside the while loop to create a new struct.

```
while(file >> number_student >> name_student >> surname_student >> code_student)
{ 
    Student student = { number_student, name_student, surname_student, code_student};
    students.add(student);
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro for your support.  I appreciate it.  Student students is related to  Student.h and Student.cpp.  Sorry, I made a mistake - it is Student student( without "s" at the end), I decided to put it into main.cpp just for accessing to Student, I do not whether it is good idea or not. I want to read file and store the informations in a new dynamic array  - DynamicArray<Students> students. I must follow the instructions of my teacher ))).

Comment: In order to store the information you must at least put the information into your Student. Your code read the file and store the data on multiple variables which didn't have anything to do with Student. You must assign those variables to variables in Student if you want your code to actually store them. This is not about following the instruction of your teacher, your code shows lack of fundamental understanding in how struct/class work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can anyone show me how to read a file and store elements in a dynamic array? I just need a simple exemple. Let's store it in DynamicArray<Kid> kids.